# Places to drink (party) at Songnae Korea

Tags: south-korea, nightlife, seoul

I'm visiting Songnae South Korea, and I wanted to know (since I didn't find any) if there are bars or places to go and have a couple of drinks.

Answer (score 4):

Songnae is a suburb of Seoul.  In addition to the random drinking holes you'll find around the station (and any station in Seoul), you've got a one-seat ride on subway line 1 to [Yongsan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Seoul/Yongsan), Seoul's largest foreigner-friendly nightlife district, and a single transfer to [Hongdae/Sinchon](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Seoul/Seodaemun-Mapo), for the Korean and nightclub experiences.

Comment: I can't speak for Yongsan but I always found Hongdae to have a good mix of mostly Koreans with some foreigners mixed in. Foreigners are mostly English teachers from the US. People from US military bases are often banned from the area, which is a good thing, since I never saw a bar fight or street fight not involving them.